# Translate a Constant while appeasing WordPress PHPCS

Tags: escaping, coding-standards

The following *works* but isn't up to snuff with [PHP Code Sniffer WordPress coding standards](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards)

```
<?php esc_html_e( ADDRESS, 'wprig' ); ?>
```

Linter yells at me with:

> [WordPress.WP.I18n.NonSingularStringLiteralText] The $text arg must be a single string literal, not "ADDRESS".

The following, for aforementioned error, also don't work:

```
<?php esc_html_e( (string)ADDRESS, 'wprig' ); ?>
<?php esc_html_e( strval(ADDRESS), 'wprig' ); ?>
<?php esc_attr_e( ADDRESS, 'wprig' ); ?>
```

I know [constants can be exploited](https://vip.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/the-importance-of-escaping-all-the-things/) so it is needed. Any way to make this work besides `//phpcs:ignore`, or is this not good practice and I should redo my use of constants?

Comment: Hey, nobody at VIP uses those standards and they're in the process of being deprecated, also don't use constants in translation APIs, see https://github.com/Automattic/VIP-Coding-Standards for better VIP coding standards. Additionally, if you're working on a VIP project you can raise a ticket

Comment: My bad, double checked and I'm using `WordPress` standards. I've got the WordPress-VIP as default but project *is* using just `WordPress`. (And no, not working on a VIP project, I wish)

Comment: You should avoid the VIP standards that come bundled with WPCS, they're unmaintained and don't reflect the actual VIP standards that VIP uses

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use constants or anything other than actual strings with translation functions.

This is because the code that reads your code, and produces the translatable strings does not actually *run* your code, it is *reading* your code.

Here is a more detailed post on the topic:

http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/

But the short version is this:

This is wrong:

```
<?php esc_html_e( ADDRESS, 'wprig' ); ?>
```

Nothing will make that right except this:

```
<?php esc_html_e( 'Actual String here', 'wprig' ); ?>
```

Comment: _"does not actually run your code, it is reading your code "_ Ahhh, that clears that up. Makes perfect sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a hard time finding the proper solution if it wasn't a constant.

This works for a variable and the `value` attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $image_id ); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of WordPress,

> a variable and should not be part of the translation

Thus, you need to use printf instead of _e (echo). Thus the `<?php esc_html_e( ADDRESS, 'wprig' ); ?>` will be

```
esc_html(
    printf(
        __( '%s', 'wprig' ),
        ADDRESS // it can simply be a normal variable 
    )

);
```

[Documentation from WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/#variables)